# Is it possible that many layout in one layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design that layout , like my photo , there are three buttons , can let me show different function in screen , I don't know how use fragment to 
achieve my goals?

Does anyone any suggestion can help me ?

Thanks.
[image]

Edit : I have already solved.

Comment: yes..possible.. use fragment ..

Comment: Are you trying to show different content or different layouts? If it is different content, you can use fragment and replace the fragment on button click. If it is only layout, you can use 3 different xml layout with or without using <include layout .. > tag and hide/show it whenever needed.

Comment: Use include for including layout .  And To remain in the Same Activity you can use fragment.

Comment: The best option is use Fragment.

Comment: Thanks all of you so quick to answer my question.

Comment: @Aveek: I know hide/show layout , but the app will get slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities consist of different layouts.Only one layout can run in one activity.But Fragments can be used in this respect.You need to add frame layout at the places where you need different layout.Fragments have similar life cycle as compare to that of the activities.You will need to create fragments and add it in the activity through its java file.
Hope this helps you.Reply back for more details.

Comment: Guess only Fragment can do that.

Comment: yes in your activity layout file, add frame layouts (build layouts of Fragments) and attach it in Activity java file.

Comment: thanks Leona lin you selected my answer as correct

Comment: but even I use fragment , there are still some things confused me.
see my photo , only one screen will be change , three buttons and top button are fixed.

Comment: what are those ??

Comment: If I mean right only that layout will be added while rest are buttons which are fixed.Still there there is no problem. 1st you will copy the RelativeLayout. place a frame layout in its place and then use a fragment to replace the content inside it and its use it as you want.